# FQL: get recent photos of your friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get most recent photos (last 100) published by my friends.

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100
```

Problem is, that the result seems to be wrong. It looks like, that photos I am receiving are photos of my most recent friends. So that it finds 100 photos of "latest" friends, then query execution is terminated, photos are sorted and returned.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to grab the most recent photo for 100 of your friends who have recently used Facebook, I would do the following (there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this in a single query, you might want to look into batch/multi requests).

Grab 100 friends who have most recently updated their profile

> SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1
>   = me()) ORDER BY profile_update_time DESC LIMIT 100

For each friend uid, query for their most recent photo (eg. uid 123). This can be automated with a simple for-loop.

> SELECT src_big, created FROM photo WHERE owner = 123 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this is not the way I should go. Because to get this data you must do 101 queries (sure I can make multiquery, but still this is not a good way to go). Because this will not reflect your feed. I need to keep "time consistency"...

Comment: Also your solution will not give me data I am expecting. Idea is to simulate your facebook feed, but just with photos. That means I need timeline of photos sorted by created_at, published by my friends.

Comment: I agree, 101 queries is far from optimal, but from your original question, that seems to be the only feasible way to accomplish the task. If you used batch processing, combined with multi-queries, you can actually get the number of requests down to 3 (batch requests allow for 50 queries at a time). You original question is a bit unclear, which 100 friends do you want to select?

Comment: If you wanted to select the most recent 100 friends to have interacted with facebook, you could try this query: SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY profile_update_time DESC) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100 . Also keep in mind that most people tend to upload many photos at once, so this could skew your photos feed idea (if one person uploads an album, you run the risk of only seeing their photos). I hope this helps, cheers.